# need to convert this time format to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I use to be able to parse this correctly on my app from an API endpoint:

start_time: "2013-12-12T19:30:00Z"

But after the server move it started to look like this now

start_time: "2014-10-01T20:00:00.000Z"

can you tell me what happened and how I can restore it back to the earlier one before the server move?

Would also love to know what the T and the 00.000Z stands for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a problem with the latter format?  Time.parse still handles it just fine, no?

```
> Time.zone.parse  "2014-10-01T20:00:00.000Z"
=> Wed, 01 Oct 2014 20:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

The 'T' comes from the ISO8601 standard (as does all the rest actually).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

The 'Z' is a shortcut for UTC.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC

The "00.000" is seconds and fractions of a second.